# Generating a table of content line without related page number

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, overleaf

I have some unnumbered pages in a document before pages that are numbered. I'd like to add the unnumbered pages to the table of contents, but without their page number.

Here is an exemple:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

%%%% UNNUMBERED PAGES %%%%

\setcounter{page}{-100}     % Makes the unnumbered pages far below 0 to avoid glossary to point at them instead of the numbered pages

\tableofcontents    % Generates the table of contents
\thispagestyle{empty}   % No page number on the table of contents page


\newpage
\printglossary[type=main,title={Technical vocabulary}]  % Generates the glossary
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TECHNICAL VOCABULARY}    % Makes the glossary appear in the table of content
\thispagestyle{empty}   % No page number on the glossary page


\newglossaryentry{yp}   % Glossary entry example to make it appear
{
    name=yeepee,
    description={The glossary appears!}
}

%%%% NUMBERED PAGES %%%%

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}    % Page numbering begins here

\chapter{Introduction}

\gls{yp}

\end{document}
```

In this document, I'd like to add "Technical vocabulary" to the table of contents without making "-99" appear in it.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `\thepage`, that does not show the page number. Often `\pagenumbering{gobble}` is used, but this would result in page anchor duplicates. So I prefer a definition that still gives a page number for `hyperref`, e.g.

```
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{}{\Roman{page}}}
```

or

```
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{}{F-\arabic{page}}}
```

But there are some other issues with your code. For example, if the glossary would have more than one page, the ToC entry would be the one of the last page (or even the next one) instead of the first. Also all the `\thispagestyle{empty}` are not needed and could also be too late.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}% run makeindex automatically
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

%%%% UNNUMBERED PAGES %%%%

\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{}{F-\arabic{page}}}% F = frontmatter,
                                                            % but you can use whatever you want.
  
\tableofcontents    % Generates the table of contents

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TECHNICAL VOCABULARY}    % Makes the glossary
                                % appear in the table of content with the
                                % first page of the glossary!
\printglossary[type=main,title={Technical vocabulary}]  % Generates the glossary

\newglossaryentry{yp}   % Glossary entry example to make it appear
{
    name=yeepee,
    description={The glossary appears!}
}

%%%% NUMBERED PAGES %%%%

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\gls{yp}

\end{document}
```

These are the three pages of the document:

[image: the three pages of the document]

and here are the bookmarks:

[image: bookmarks]

To change the `F-` in the bookmarks you can change the second argument of `\texorpdfstring` in the (temporary) redefinition of `\thepage`. To change the page number in `F-2`, e.g., start it with `F-1` you can change the `page` counter. Such changes will not effect the table of contents, as long as the first argument of `\texorpdfstring` is empty.

I've also added option `automake` to run `makeindex` automatically. But if you like to use running `makeglossaries` manually instead, feel free to remove the option.

Comment: You're so fast I deleted my answer before I saw you replied! (For future readers, I placed `\thispagestyl{empty}` there because in my full document I wanted to remove fancy headers and footers for table of contents and glossary, but this removed them only for their last pages if they were more than 1 page long). I bypassed the problem simply by defining fancy headers and footers after the table of contents and glossary instead of defining them at the beginning, trying to remove them for some pages and then putting them again (this was not really clever). Thank you for your help!